# Rename file by moving middle string to end of the filename

Tags: bash, rename

I have some data files and I wish to rename them for my pipeline.

The files look like this:

```
{unique_ids}_{experiment_condition}_L{3_digit_number}.txt
```

I need to rename them so the experiment condition flag will appear at the end of the filename, before the extension as follows:

```
{unique_ids}_L{3_digit_number}_{experiment_condition}.txt
```

Length of unique_ids and experiment_condition is not fixed.

Example:

`ghad312fd2_Mb_L002.txt` becomes `ghad312fd2_L002_Mb.txt`.

Thank You!

Comment: Do `unique_ids` or `experiment_condition` contain underscores?

Comment: What operating system are you using? Do you have the perl `rename` command? What is the output of `file $(readlink -f $(which rename))`?

Comment: Also, you say you have `{unique_ids}_L{3_digit_number}_{experiment_condition}.txt`, but your example file name (`ghad312fd2_Mb_L002.txt`) is `{unique_ids}_{experiment_condition}_L{3_digit_number}.txt`. Can you give us a clearer example?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using the Perl-based `rename` utility to rename all the files in the current directory matching the pattern `./*_*_*.txt` (i.e. any file whose nome contains at least two underscores and ends with `.txt`):

```bsh
rename -n 's/([^_]+)_([^_]+)\.txt$/$2_$1.txt/' ./*_*_*.txt
```

This swaps the last two underscore-delimited parts of the filename, excluding the filename suffix `.txt`.  Remove `-n` to run this for real after ensuring that it seems to be doing the correct thing.

Comment: @Cbhihe You will have to try installing both. On my (OpenBSD) system, the utility is actually called `prename`.  I would be somewhat surprised if a name collision between the two utilities wasn't appropriately handled somehow.

Comment: I did think you were on BSD :-). I just found out that on Archlinux, installing `perl-rename` does preserve the default utility GNU `rename`. Tx.

Comment: @Cbhihe, AFAIK, there's no GNU `rename`. There's (a quite dumb) one in `util-linux` though, which might be the one installed on your system.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas: You are (depressingly) correct on both counts: there is no specific GNU-flavored `rename` and the util-linux version installed by default is really "pared down" to bare bones compared to `perl-rename`. Instead the nifty regex based  in-place substitution capability of `perl-rename` blew me away. `perl` rules !  (at least sometimes).

Comment: @Cbhihe, yes even [the original `rename` from 33 years ago](https://github.com/Perl/perl5/blob/a687059cbaf2c6fdccb5e0fae2aee80ec15625a8/eg/rename) written as 10 lines of perl code was infinitely better than `util-linux`'s (itself added around 2000 in 2.10e, annoying many Linux users at the time when some distributions started including it)

Answer (score 6):

With the `zsh` shell:

```
autoload zmv
zmv  -n '(*)(_*)(_L[0-9](#c3))(.txt)' '$1$3$2$4'
```

(remove `-n` (dry-run) if happy).

`[0-9](#c3)` matches a sequence of 3 ASCII decimal digits. You can also use `<0-999>` to match on numbers from 0 to 999 (bearing in mind it would also match on 0000123) or `<->` for any number (any sequence of one or more ASCII decimal digits).

Answer (score 5):

Try also

```
for FN in gh*; do IFS="_." read ID XC NR EXT <<< "$FN"; echo mv -- "$FN" "${ID}_${NR}_${XC}.${EXT}"; done
```

It `read`s four variables from the respective file name in the "here string", and reconstructs the new file name from them.
Remove the `echo` if happy with what you are seeing.

Comment: Dont use all upper case for non-exported shell variable names to avoid clashing with existing variables and obfuscating your code, see [correct-bash-and-shell-script-variable-capitalization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/673055/correct-bash-and-shell-script-variable-capitalization)

Comment: @EdMorton The argument for case on shell variables seems to be mixed. The accepted answer in your link says to use all lower-case but the comments, including some from long-time Bell Labs employees, have reasons for not sticking to lower case. Readability and distinction from commands are the major arguments.

Comment: @doneal24 there's one person in the comments arguing for all upper case names and claiming to be an ex Bell Labs employee. As someone who worked at AT&T/Bell Labs/Lucent/etc. for 30 years myself I promise you that being a long term Bell Labs employee doesn't offer any particular authority on shell conventions, it just means you're old. You don't see people using all upper case variable names for readability and distinction from library functions, etc. in C, Java, Go, or any other non-ancient programming language so the argument you should do so in shell just doesn't hold water.

Comment: @EdMorton Starting as an F77 programmer, that probably qualifies me as both "old" and "ancient" in your comment. :)  Saying that because you don't see people doing this in Java is not really an argument for not doing so in shell. Different languages, different necessities. If you know you're not going to conflict with env variables, why not use upper case?

Comment: I also started with Fortran around 1978, manually writing programs on graph paper that were snail-mailed to the local college where a secretary typed them onto punch cards for a tech to run through the mainframe to snail-mail the output back a week later telling me that I forgot a semi-colon. Saying "why do it if you know..." is very much like saying if you know you're not going to crash why wear a seat belt? Just like quoting variables, you don't avoid all upper-case variables to protect against what you know about, you do it to protect against surprises.

Comment: @doneal24 for some examples, if you look at the well-respected, frequently referenced, and constantly reviewed bash FAQ, https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ, I would be shocked if you see any non-exported variables that are all upper case unless they're in a "what not to do" section. I couldn't find any by poking around just now.

Answer (score 3):

I propose this:

```bsh
for i in *.txt; do 
  n="${i%%.*}"
  id="$(echo "$n" | cut -d_ -f1)"
  e="$(echo "$n" | cut -d_ -f2)"
  d="$(echo "$n" | cut -d_ -f3)"
  echo mv -- "$i" "${id}_${d}_${e}.txt"
done
```

If you are happy with the result given by `echo...`, remove it and leave `mv -- "$i" "${id}_${d}_${e}.txt"` which will actually move the file.

Comment: I think the last line should be removed.

Comment: Does this spawn six child processes for each file to rename? Due to `$( | )` expansion.

Comment: @rexkogitans right, removed, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `unique_ids` has no underscore, put this in a script and run it with GNU `sed` or any other `sed` that supports `-E`, giving your file names as arguments:

```
#!/bin/bash
for f in "$@" ; do
    new_name=$(echo "$f" | sed -E 's/([^_]+)_(.+)_(L[0-9]{3})\.txt/\1_\3_\2.txt/g')
    echo "$f -> $new_name"
    mv "$f" "$new_name"
done
```

Answer (score 2):

With `sh`:

```
for f in *.txt
do
    # Getting the extension
    ext=".${f##*[.]}"

    # Get the 3 digit number part
    ext_trail="${f%[.]*}"
    digit_number="L${ext_trail##*_L}"

    # tmp variable to get the first two
    tmp="${ext_trail%_*}"

    # Get the experiment conditions
    experimental_condition="${tmp#*_}"

    # Get the unique id
    unique_id="${tmp%_*}"


    echo mv -- "$f" "${unique_id}_${digit_number}_${experimental_condition}${ext}"
done
```

---

With `bash`:

```
for f in *.txt
do
    [[ "$f" =~ ^([^_]*)_([^_]*)(_L[0-9]{3})[.]txt ]] &&
        echo mv -- "$f" "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}${BASH_REMATCH[3]}_${BASH_REMATCH[2]}.txt"
done
```

Answer (score 2):

Try [`mmv`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/mmv.1):

```bsh
mmv '*_*_*.txt' '#1_#3_#2.txt'
```

It obviously only works if there are no other underscores present in the file names.

Answer (score 1):

If the format is very robust like that, try to incorporate this:

```bsh
echo ghad312fd2_Mb_L002.txt | awk -F'[_.]' -v OFS=_ '{ print $1, $3, $2 "." $4 }'
```

output: `ghad312fd2_L002_Mb.txt`

Could look like this in a script:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
for f in *.txt; do
    mv -v -- "$f" "$(awk -F'[_.]' -v OFS=_ '{ print $1, $3, $2 "." $4 }' <<<"$f")"
done
```